# Change country field when MuiPhoneNumber country code is selected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

I have this code that requires a phone number and country to be submitted via a phone. However, I am having a big challenge having these two unconnected fields working together. The MuiPhoneNumber field uses `material-ui-phone-number-2` package, while the country field is a simple autocomplete field that uses local javascript code that has an array of countries. What I need to achieve is that, when the user selects phones country code from the MuiPhoneNumber, the country field should be selected automatically unless the user chooses to change, which is highly unlikely. I have managed to change these values via formik using the onChange property of MuiPhoneNumber field, but the problem is that the display value for the country is not changed when the formik value changes programmatically. here is my code to put this into perspective.

phone and country mui fields:

```
    <div className="flex">
                            <MuiPhoneNumber 
                                defaultCountry={'us'}
                                preferredCountries={['fr', 'in', 'it', 'mx', 'es', 'gb', 'us']}
                                onChange={handlePhoneChange}
                                fullWidth
                                name="phone"
                                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                defaultValue={formik.values.phone}
                                error={Boolean(formik.touched.phone && formik.errors.phone)}
                                helperText={formik.touched.phone && formik.errors.phone}
                                label="Phone Number (Optional)"
                                placeholder="Phone Number (Optional)"
                                margin="normal"
                                type="text"
                                variant="outlined"
                                InputProps={{
                                    classes: textFieldClasses
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex">
                            <Autocomplete
                                fullWidth
                                options={allCountries}
                                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                                defaultValue={defaultCountry}
                                isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
                                onChange={(_, value) => handleSelectedCountry(value)}
                                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                renderInput={({ inputProps, ...rest }) => (
                                    <TextField 
                                        {...rest}
                                        inputProps={{ ...inputProps, readOnly: true }}
                                        error={Boolean(formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country)}
                                        fullWidth
                                        helperText={formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country}
                                        label="Country"
                                        placeholder="Country"
                                        margin="normal"
                                        {...formik.getFieldProps('country')}
                                        type="text"
                                        variant="outlined"
                                        classes={textFieldClasses}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        </div>
```

Here is the useState for managing the defaultCountry value:

`const [defaultCountry, setDefaultCountry] = useState<DefaultCountryType>();`

Here is the useEffect code for changing defaultCountry value, as well as the handle change functions for phone and country fields:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const country = allCountries.find(country => country.name === formik.values.country)
        if (country) {
            setDefaultCountry(country)
        }
    }, [formik?.values?.country])

    const handlePhoneChange = (value?: string | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, allData?: AllDataType) => {
        formik.setFieldValue("phone", value, false)
        formik.setFieldValue("country", allData?.name, false)
    }

    const handleSelectedCountry = (value: Country | null) => {
        formik.setFieldValue("country", value?.name, false);
    }
```

How can I resolve this issue? I believe the problem is with the mui autocomplete component not being able to change when default value changes.